# Make DVD legible in CD drive?

Tags: laser, hacking

Don't laugh just yet.

I'm well aware that it's impossible to normally read a DVD because the data tracks several times smaller. However, would it be possible to write double/triple tracks so that the surface would be large enough for a CD writer to use? Somewhat similar to how regular 1080p and 4k/retina scaling works.

Edit:
Or might it perhaps be possible to burn DVD data first, then stop and switch drives, and then write CD style data to it? I presume this also isn't possible because of the layer depths?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: Apart from the wavelength problem, which could conceivably be overcome by writing several identical tracks, the DVD uses a continuous spiral track, so there's no fixed relationship between the bits in adjacent tracks, and no way to write a wider, larger pitch spiral.

Comment: Most DVD writers also write CD's, I don't see what the problem is. They are 12USD. You can't use one technology in place of the other, the writer needs to support both. If you really wanted to hack things I suppose anything is possible, but you could spend a year or three of hacking to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

No, not possible:

Start reading on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_disc) explaining how CD/DVD actually works

Then look at:

[image]

Note the differences between CD and DVD. The dimensions of this pits are different, the wavelenght of the light is different.

Even of you'd manage to make the DVD tracks align such that they'd look like a CD track (and that by itself will be a challenge) then the CD optical unit is incapable of reading the tracks because they will still have the wrong dimensions.

Scaling 1080p to 4k is something completely different. They're just video modes describing the amount of pixels. Amounts of pixels can easily be converted /changed in software.

Comment: I meant the retina displays mostly as a visual aid. I didn't realize the different drives have different layer depths for the data and that screws things up. I'm gonna look up how dual layer DVDs pull that off.

Comment: The depth of the data layer within the disk is not the issue here, and the laser focusing mechanism is more than capable of dealing with that anyway. The key issue is the depth of the pits within each data layer, which is specific to the wavelength of the light being used to read them. A pit is detected based on the interference that occurs between light reflected from the bottom of the pit and light reflected from the surrounding non-pit area. The best SNR occurs when the pits are a quarter wavelength deep and the laser spot illuminates approximately equal areas of pit and non-pit.

Comment: However, readout wavelength is not nearly as important with dye-based or phase-change writeable disks, which absorb or scatter the light in order to create a detectable signal. With these, it is at least *theoretically possible* (using a heavily modified writer) to create a pattern of fine dots that would mimic the coarser track that a CD reader is expecting to find, in much the same way that a halftone pattern is used to print a picture in a magazine or newspaper.